# request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to serve up different pages based on whether a user is a bot or not, so I placed this code in the routes.rb file:

```
request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].include? "bot"
```

And get this error:

```
block in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `request' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007fe30f329f98> (NameError)
```

Any ideas how I can make this work?

Been looking around and found this, but it still gives me an error:

```
constraints :user_agent => /bot/ do
    root :to => "events#index"
  end
  constraints :user_agent => /^((?!bot).)*$/ do
    root :to => "main#index"
  end
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want [routing constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints).

For example:

```
# Routes matched in order specified, so this will be checked first
constraints :user_agent => /bot/ do
  root :to => "events#index", as: :bot_root
end

# If the above route didn't apply, this one should happen instead
root :to => "main#index"
```

The `as: :bot_root` should help avoid the root naming conflict

Comment: how could i modify this to make the first one includes "bot" and the second one for anything else?

Comment: From the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html): "Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified". So, just do the first one, then beneath just do a normal route. Will update answer to reflect.

Comment: after the edit I get `Invalid route name, already in use: 'root'`

Comment: No worries, those problems can be really frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the built-in `:constraints` parameter for routes. The general how-to can be found [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints), and there's a nice [blog post](http://www.railsdispatch.com/posts/rails-3-makes-life-better) that explains how to filter based on the user-agent string. Looks like you can put something like

```
get "/page" => "page#show", :bot => true, :constraints => {:user_agent => /bot/}
```

in your routes.rb file.